# Mysql deadlock on column update

Tags: mysql

Have run into this weird problem where a simple query fails due to a deadlock
Here is the query

```
UPDATE myprobelmatictable SET  mycolumn = (mycolum-0)  WHERE id = '59'
```

The weird issue is that this query fails only when my php server is located on a slower server on a remote network

Before I run this query, the following happens

```
transaction starts

insert new row in table 5

select 1 row from myproblematictable

insert new row in table 6

update table 4

UPDATE myprobelmatictable SET  mycolumn = (mycolum-0)  WHERE id = '<id>'

update table 3

Commit Transaction
```

The strange thing is that the  same query fails each time with the following error

```
Error Number: 1213</p><p>Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

The innodb status command does not seem to mention myproblematictable

any clues?

Comment: Why are you even doing an `UPDATE ... SET x=x-0`? It's a non-operation.

Comment: @tadman: it may not be a "non-operation". it really depends on the datatype of `x`. For example, if `x` is `VARCHAR` and contains `'123ABC'`...

Comment: I know. That's a missing optimization but that 0 could also be a 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: the column in question is a float and the values can be 0 ,0.1, 1.2  anything

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Comment: Are there any foreign keys on this table or pointing to this table from other tables ? Show structures of your tables. Also, are there any triggers that modify data in other tables ? If yes, show these triggers.

Comment: Are there any other transactions active that update rows in `myprobelmatictable` before your transaction (without committing) and are now "waiting" for table 4,5 or 6.

Comment: Not using any foreign keys or triggers that are defined on the tables. The tables in question are high volume and updated very very frequently. The only time this error occurs is when the PHP server in slower and in a different DC.

Answer (score 0):

This can be the result of another query updating the tables in a different order.  I would try to see if there's a pre-determined order in which the tables should be updated, and if so, rewriting the order of the updates.

If not, I would suggest trying to find the offending quer(ies), and seeing what order they are updating the tables.  What type of table engine are you using?  Keep in mind that MyISAM locks the entire table.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that you ran a "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;".  I would suggest going through that result text to find any tables currently being locked.  You can simply paste the result into a text editor, and search for the word "lock".